# shm_server gives open error for other user when executing same program

Tags: c, file, ipc, shared-memory, segment

we are working on Linux red hat server to practice interprocess communication . everyone in our class connect to server using telnet as different users.

i have compiled and executed my server.c & client.c at first it work's  without error but for my classmates it gives **open error** when executing server.c
(for me it still works) and  when my friend executes client.c program it print's file content that i shared

for Reference,
https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node27.html#SECTION002730000000000000000

SERVER.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>
#define SHMSZ 40
int main()
{
        char ch;
        int shmid,fo,n,i;
        char fname[SHMSZ];
     char buff[600];
     char *shm,*s;
     int key=3600;
     if((shmid=shmget(key,SHMSZ,IPC_CREAT|0666))<0)
             printf("\nOpen Error");
     if((shm=shmat(shmid,NULL,0))==(char*)-1)
            printf("\nOpen Error");
     s=shm;
     system("clear");
        printf("\n server is accepting the file name:");
        printf("\n Enter the file name:");
     scanf("%s",&fname);
        fo=open(fname,O_RDWR);
            if(fo<0)                   // here it fails
                printf("\n Open error");
            else
            {
                i=0;
                while(read(fo,buff,sizeof(buff))!=0)
                {
                    for(i=0;i<strlen(buff);i++)
                        *s++=buff[i-1];
                }
                *s='\0';
                printf("\nClient is loading\n");\
                while(*shm!='*')
                    sleep(1);
                printf("\nClient finished into work");
         }
}
```

client.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#define SHMSZ 40
int main()
{
    int shmid;
    int key=3600;
    char *shm,*s;
if((shmid=shmget(key,SHMSZ,0666))<0)
            printf("\nShmat error");
    if((shm=shmat(shmid,NULL,0))==(char*)-1)
            printf("\nShmat error");
        system("clear");
        printf("\nThis is the client");
        printf("\nReading the content in the memory");
        *shm='*';
        for(s=shm;*s!='\0';s++)
            putchar(*s);
        putchar('\n');

}
```

expected output:
Server Side

```
[it@itserver it]$ cc ipcshms.c
[it@itserver it]$ ./a.out
Server is accepting the filename
Enter the filename:sum.c  //shared file
Client is Loading
Client finished its work
```

Client Side

```
[it@itserver it]$ cc ipcshmc.c
[it@itserver it]$ ./a.out
This is client
Reading the content in memory //shared file content
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        printf("Hi");
}
```

i triedto ask my professor about it he refused to lend his ear

what could make `if` condition to fail and give open error in server.c?

P.S:

if i change segment will it work?

Comment: If you get an error from a system call, check `errno` to see *why* it failed. Use e.g. the `perror` function instead of `printf` to print a nice message from `errno`.

Comment: On an unrelated note, by default output to `stdout` is *line buffered*. That means the output is flushed when you print a newline (`'\n'`). If you print leading newlines, that newline will be printed together with the *previous* output but nut the output you actually have in the`printf` call. Try to make it a habit to have *trailing* newlines instead. I.e. do `printf("This is the client\n");` instead.

Comment: FWIW, cramming everything into an `if` statement, such as with `if((shm=shmat(shmid,NULL,0))==(char*)-1)`, is a horrible coding style.  First, it's overly-complex.  How many extra sets of parenthesis did you have to add to make it work properly?  Second, it's *extremely* bug-prone because of the unnecessary complexity.  Third, it's just about impossible to add any real error-processing code in a way that isn't also extremely complex.  No one gets extra credit for stuffing as much code into as few lines as possible.

Comment: it is a lab exercise @AndrewHenle it new for me ,

Comment: @AndrewHenle do you think changing memory address (content address) will work ?

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem . the problem every one in my class typed this program from given material which had misplaced semicolon in here

```
if((shm=shmat(shmid,NULL,0))==(char*)-1);
```

hence it executes next line which states "open error".

and while opening file they chose the file which i had  that they didn't (file didn't exist in their directory )

so it lead to another problem